# NextJS with Aws Amplify deployment error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

Does anyone has tried AWS-Amplify for next.js deployment? I am getting this error always that "yarn build" successful but didn't deployed and failed.

[image]

Git repo is configured with auto-deployment and YML file for aws-amplify is below.

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - rm -rf node_modules
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: Please help to share the scripts section in your package.json

Comment: Did you end up solving your issue?

Comment: Amplify is often hard to debug as it acts like a black box. Check out SST, it deploys Next.js apps to your AWS account using CDK which is backed by CloudFormation template. So you have full control over what's being built and deploy. It's fully compatible with Next.js 11. Here's an example https://serverless-stack.com/examples/how-to-create-a-nextjs-app-with-serverless.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this yaml file in your build

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: public
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```